# How to use C++ in Linux to get information about the motherboard?

Tags: c++, motherboard

For CPU in Linux:

```
// ...
string str;
ifstream file("/proc/cpuinfo");
while (file) {
  std::getline(file, str);
  if (str.find("model name") != std::string::npos) {
    // ...
  }
  else
  if (str.find("vendor_id") != std::string::npos) {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

You can get information about the processor. And how to get information about the motherboard using C++ in Linux?

Thanks friends!

Comment: What information do you require?

Comment: name, manufacturer, chipset, serialNumber

Comment: Maybe here `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_xxx` where `xxx` is things like `name` and `vendor`.

Comment: More question. Dmidecode must be run through sudo. How to do it in the program? Or daemon and so works through sudo?

Comment: @VitaliyBarilko The user has to run your program with `sudo` or as a privileged user.